# VS2022 only looks at card reader when signing

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, code-signing, smartcard-reader

When clicking Select from Store option for signing ClickOnce manifests, VS2022 only wants to look at the card reader attached to my computer and not the actual certificate store. What do I need to do to force it to ignore the card reader?

This happens regardless of whether a card in inserted.

Comment: Can't you choose 'select from file' to use the pfx file directly?

Comment: It's an option in the IDE but the certificate is installed with no export and the build machine isn't access controlled so keeping a local .pfx copy isn't considered secure. I've been debugging it with a self-signed cert, and it's starting to look like the VS tool ignores certs in Local Computer, and only looks at certs in Current User before falling back to installed smart card reader. Seems to be a SignTool.exe limitation (still trying to point it to the desired store.